# Parse out key=value pairs into variables

Tags: bash, awk

I have a bunch of different kinds of files I need to look at periodically, and what they have in common is that the lines have a bunch of `key=value` type strings. So something like:

```
Version=2 Len=17 Hello Var=Howdy Other
```

I would like to be able to reference the names directly from awk... so something like:

```
cat some_file | ... | awk '{print Var, $5}' # prints Howdy Other
```

How can I go about doing that?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to use awk? Associative arrays (what some other languages call maps or hashes) are available in native bash as well.

Comment: Also, could you explain the parsing rules a bit more explicitly? I'd expect the above to assign `Len=17 Hello` -- grouping the `Hello` word with the value for `Len` -- since the given behavior of `Var=Howdy Other` relies on implicitly grouping all words not containing `=` signs as extensions of the previous word's content.

Comment: In the question's output, `Var` is `Howdy`. The `Other` comes from `$5`. Or so I read it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Values won't have spaces. So `Len=17` is one word that sets that variable, and `Hello` is another word that doesn't set anything.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy How would you do it in bash?

Comment: @Barry: I added an answer demonstrating same.

Comment: Cannot you do it in the dirty way? I.e. use `=` as the field separator and print the last field.

Answer (score 10):

The closest you can get is to parse the variables into an associative array first thing every line. That is to say,

```
awk '{ delete vars; for(i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) { n = index($i, "="); if(n) { vars[substr($i, 1, n - 1)] = substr($i, n + 1) } } Var = vars["Var"] } { print Var, $5 }'
```

More readably:

```
{
  delete vars;                   # clean up previous variable values
  for(i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) {     # walk through fields
    n = index($i, "=");          # search for =
    if(n) {                      # if there is one:

                                 # remember value by name. The reason I use
                                 # substr over split is the possibility of
                                 # something like Var=foo=bar=baz (that will
                                 # be parsed into a variable Var with the
                                 # value "foo=bar=baz" this way).
      vars[substr($i, 1, n - 1)] = substr($i, n + 1)
    }
  }

  # if you know precisely what variable names you expect to get, you can
  # assign to them here:
  Var     = vars["Var"]
  Version = vars["Version"]
  Len     = vars["Len"]
}
{
  print Var, $5                  # then use them in the rest of the code
}
```

Comment: Nice. I guess you want `<=` in `for(i = 1; i <= NF; ++i)` though, to process the last key-value pair too. Also, `print vars["Var"]` without any temporary variable works too.

Comment: @Arjan You're right about `<= NF`, of course; thank you. I fixed it in the answer. You're also right that it works without the `Var`, `Version` and `Len` variables if you use `vars[foo]` directly; they're just there to make the code in the question work.

Answer (score 6):

```
$ cat file | sed -r 's/[[:alnum:]]+=/\n&/g' | awk -F= '$1=="Var"{print $2}'
Howdy Other
```

Or, avoiding the useless use of cat:

```
$ sed -r 's/[[:alnum:]]+=/\n&/g' file | awk -F= '$1=="Var"{print $2}'
Howdy Other
```

#### How it works

- `sed -r 's/[[:alnum:]]+=/\n&/g'`

  This places each key,value pair on its own line.
- `awk -F= '$1=="Var"{print $2}'`

  This reads the key-value pairs.  Since the field separator is chosen to be `=`, the key ends up as field 1 and the value as field 2.  Thus, we just look for lines whose first field is `Var` and print the corresponding value.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest and easiest way is to use the string substitution like this:

```
property='my.password.is=1234567890=='
name=${property%%=*}
value=${property#*=}
echo "'$name' : '$value'"
```

The output is:

```
'my.password.is' : '1234567890=='
```

Yore.

Answer (score 4):

Since discussion in commentary has made it clear that a pure-bash solution would also be acceptable:

```
#!/bin/bash
case $BASH_VERSION in
  ''|[0-3].*) echo "ERROR: Bash 4.0 required" >&2; exit 1;;
esac

while read -r -a words; do                # iterate over lines of input
  declare -A vars=( )                  # refresh variables for each line
  set -- "${words[@]}"                 # update positional parameters
  for word; do
    if [[ $word = *"="* ]]; then       # if a word contains an "="...
       vars[${word%%=*}]=${word#*=}    # ...then set it as an associative-array key
    fi
  done
  echo "${vars[Var]} $5"              # Here, we use content read from that line.
done <<<"Version=2 Len=17 Hello Var=Howdy Other"
```

The `<<<"Input Here"` could also be `<file.txt`, in which case lines in the file would be iterated over.

If you wanted to use `$Var` instead of `${vars[Var]}`, then substitute `printf -v "${word%%=*}" %s "${word*=}"` in place of `vars[${word%%=*}]=${word#*=}`, and remove references to `vars` elsewhere. Note that this doesn't allow for a good way to clean up variables between lines of input, as the associative-array approach does.

Comment: This returns same Howdy Other for any of keys

Comment: @Ajeetkumar, are you sure you ran it in a shell with associative array support? That's the problem you would get if you changed `declare -A` to `declare -a` in a futile attempt to get compatibility with a version of bash older than 4.0.

Comment: Oh, I'm so sorry thats the reason. i have bash 3.2.

Comment: @Ajeetkumar, ahh. I've edited the code to replace the comment saying bash 4.0 is needed with an actual version check, which should stop others from hitting the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

I will try to explain you a very generic way to do this which you can adapt easily if you want to print out other stuff.

Assume you have a string which has a format like this:

```
key1=value1 key2=value2 key3=value3
```

or more generic

```
key1_fs2_value1_fs1_key2_fs2_value2_fs1_key3_fs2_value3
```

With `fs1` and `fs2` two different *field separators*.

You would like to make a selection or some operations with these values. To do this, the easiest is to store these in an associative array:

```
array["key1"] => value1
array["key2"] => value2
array["key3"] => value3
array["key1","full"] => "key1=value1"
array["key2","full"] => "key2=value2"
array["key3","full"] => "key3=value3"
```

This can be done with the following function in awk:

```
function str2map(str,fs1,fs2,map,   n,tmp) {
   n=split(str,map,fs1)
   for (;n>0;n--) { 
     split(map[n],tmp,fs2);
     map[tmp[1]]=tmp[2]; map[tmp[1],"full"]=map[n]
     delete map[n]
   }
}
```

So, after processing the string, you have the full flexibility to do operations in any way you like:

```
awk '
    function str2map(str,fs1,fs2,map,   n,tmp) {
       n=split(str,map,fs1)
       for (;n>0;n--) { 
         split(map[n],tmp,fs2);
         map[tmp[1]]=tmp[2]; map[tmp[1],"full"]=map[n]
         delete map[n]
       }
    }
    { str2map($0," ","=",map) }
    { print map["Var","full"] }
   ' file
```

The advantage of this method is that you can easily adapt your code to print any other key you are interested in, or even make selections based on this, example:

```
(map["Version"] < 3) { print map["var"]/map["Len"] }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using bash's `set` command, we can split the line into positional parameters like awk.
For each word, we'll try to read a name value pair delimited by =.
When we find a value, assign it to the variable named `$key` using bash's `printf -v` feature.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

line='Version=2 Len=17 Hello Var=Howdy Other'
set $line

for word in "$@"; do
    IFS='=' read -r key val <<< "$word"
    test -n "$val" && printf -v "$key" "$val"
done

echo "$Var $5"
```

output

```
Howdy Other
```

Answer (score 0):

**SYNOPSIS**

an `awk`-based solution that doesn't require manually checking the fields to locate the desired key pair :

- approach being avoid splitting unnecessary `fields` or `arrays` - only performing `regex` match via function call when needed

  - only returning ***FIRST*** occurrence of input key value. Subsequent matches along the row are NOT returned
  - i just called it `S()` cuz it's the closest letter to `$`
- I only included an array (`_`) of the 3 test values for demo purposes. Those aren't needed. In fact, no state information is being kept at all
- caveat being : key-match must be ***exact*** - this version of the code isn't for case-insensitive or fuzzy/agile matching
- Tested and confirmed working on

- ```
    - gawk 5.1.1
    - mawk 1.3.4
    - mawk-2/1.9.9.6
    - macos nawk
  ```

**CODE**

```
# gawk profile, created Fri May 27 02:07:53 2022

{m,n,g}awk '

function S(__,_) {
    return   \
    ! match($(_=_<_), "(^|["(_="[:blank:]]")")"(__)"[=][^"(_)"*") \     
        ? "^$" \
        : substr(__=substr($-_, RSTART, RLENGTH), index(__,"=")+_^!_)
}
BEGIN { OFS = "\f"                    # This array is only for testing    
      _["Version"] _["Len"] _["Var"]  # purposes. Feel free to discard at will
} { 
     for (__ in _) {
        print __, S(__) } }'
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Var
   Howdy
Len
   17
Version
       2
```

So either call the fields in BAU fashion

```
- $5, $0, $NF, etc
```

or call `S(QUOTED_KEY_VALUE)`, case-sensitive, like

- As a safeguard, to prevent mis-interpreting null strings
  or invalid inputs as `$0`, a non-match returns `^$`
  instead of empty string
- `S("Version")` to get back **`2`**.

As a bonus, it can safely handle values in multibyte `unicode`, both for values and even for keys, regardless of whether ur `awk` is `UTF-8`-aware or not :

```
 1  ✜
     
 2  Version
           2
 3  Var
       Howdy
 4  Len
       17
 5    ✜= Version=2 Len=17 Hello Var=Howdy Other
```

Answer (score -1):

I know this is particularly regarding awk but mentioning this as many people come here for solutions to break down name = value pairs ( with / without using awk as such).

I found below way simple straight forward and very effective in managing multiple spaces / commas as well -

Source: http://jayconrod.com/posts/35/parsing-keyvalue-pairs-in-bash

```
change="foo=red bar=green baz=blue"

#use below if var is in CSV (instead of space as delim)
change=`echo $change | tr ',' ' '`

for change in $changes; do
    set -- `echo $change | tr '=' ' '`
    echo "variable name == $1  and variable value == $2"
    #can assign value to a variable like below
    eval my_var_$1=$2;
done
```

Comment: `echo $change` is quite buggy -- consider the case of a value of `baz=*`; you don't want it replaced with a list of filenames that start with the string `baz=` in the current directory. And `qux="hello world"` will be parsed as `qux="hello` followed by `world"` as its own word. See [DontReadLinesWithFor](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor); and run your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fix the bugs it identifies.

Comment: Even worse than that is the use of `eval` -- if you have `$(rm$(echo)-rf$(echo)~)` as a value in your input, you don't want it executed rather than treated literally.

Comment: See [BashFAQ #6](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006) for documentation on how to **safely** perform indirect assignments. (It _is_ possible to use `eval` safely if you trust the variable names but not the values, but it's much better to use a non-`eval` approach altogether).

Comment: (This also doesn't honor the OP's requirement of ignoring words that don't contain `=` signs).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy As mentioned it was meant to only for simple case of k=v. At the time other answers were already there. I had added as a beginner I could not find a simple case first. I should have a created a separate que and then ans myself. Although thanks for ur inputs but being knowledgeable you have to be a humble especially for the ones who arent as good as you.

Comment: `k=$(rm$(echo)-rf$(echo)~)` is a `k=v` pair. At least make it `eval "my_var_$1=\$2"` -- that way you're still vulnerable to bad variable names, but not bad values. Or, much better, `printf -v "my_var_$1" %s "$2"`, to be safe in the presence of either. I don't mean to be berating, but neither do I mean to let practices with security bugs go unchallenged -- the purpose of adding answers is *for someone else to use them*, and if someone else uses the practice given in this answer to parse user-provided data, that could lead to a security breach.

Comment: I understand your security angle. I think in the illustrations we try to keep things simple and straight forward for the particular aspect we want to highlight rather than all the aspects that may be required in Production code as if these snippets will get copy pasted as is causing nuclear fallout. But I will surely be incorporating ur inputs to improve my answer. Cheers.