# Convert rows into columns for semi structured data

Tags: unix, text, awk, sed, grep

I have a data set which looks like this

```
<SUBBEGIN
    IMSI=xxxxxxxxxxxx;
    MSISDN=xxxxxxxxx;
    DEFCALL=TS11;
    CURRENTNAM=BOTH;
    CAT=COMMON;
    VOLTE_TAG=NOT_DEFINED;
    HLR_INDEX=1;
    PS_MSISDNLESS_SUPPORTED=FALSE;
    CS_MSISDNLESS_SUPPORTED=FALSE;
    CSRATTYPE=NO-NO-NO-NO-NO;
    PSRATTYPE=NO-NO-NO-NO-NO;
    ICI=NO;
    STE=NO;
<SUBEND

<SUBBEGIN
    IMSI=xxxxxxxxxxxx;
    MSISDN=xxxxxxxxx;
    DEFCALL=TS11;
    CURRENTNAM=BOTH;
    VOLTE_TAG=NOT_DEFINED;
    HLR_INDEX=1;
    PS_MSISDNLESS_SUPPORTED=FALSE;
    CS_MSISDNLESS_SUPPORTED=FALSE;
    CSRATTYPE=NO-NO-NO-NO-NO;
<SUBEND
```

This is essentially one record and this is followed by multiple rows in the same format. I want the output to be in the format as:

```
IMSI|MSISDN|DEFCALL|CURRENTNAM|CAT...
xxxx|xxxx|TS11|BOTH|COMMON|COMMON
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29108949/awk-parse-out-key-value-pairs-into-variables

Comment: @sp asic Thanks for the tip, i am able to parse through only one variable for instance IMSI in the file using `cat file | sed -r 's/[[:alnum:]]+=/\n&/g' | awk -F= '$1=="IMSI"{print $2}'`. How can i get the code to work for all the other variables

Comment: Can you use Python or Perl?

Comment: When your input can contain multiple records it's a very good idea to show at least 2 records in your sample input/output otherwise you will get solutions that work for 1 record but not for more than 1 since you only provided 1 to demonstrate your problem and for us to test against. You currently have multiple answers that will not work for 2 or more input records and answers that could maybe be simpler depending on whether or not you have blank lines between records.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {FS="[=;]"; OFS="|" }
/^<SUB/ {
    if (/END/) {
        print (hdrPrinted++ ? "" : hdr ORS ) rec
        hdr = rec = ""
    }
    next
}
{
    sub(/^[[:space:]]+/,"")
    hdr = (hdr=="" ? "" : hdr OFS) $1
    rec = (rec=="" ? "" : rec OFS) $2
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
IMSI|MSISDN|DEFCALL|CURRENTNAM|CAT|VOLTE_TAG|HLR_INDEX|PS_MSISDNLESS_SUPPORTED|CS_MSISDNLESS_SUPPORTED|CSRATTYPE|PSRATTYPE|ICI|STE
xxxxxxxxxxxx|xxxxxxxxx|TS11|BOTH|COMMON|NOT_DEFINED|1|FALSE|FALSE|NO-NO-NO-NO-NO|NO-NO-NO-NO-NO|NO|NO
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ cat test.txt
/<SUBBEGIN/ {f=1; next}      # at start flag up
/<SUBEND/ {                  # at end 
    print b ORS c            # print
    f=0; b=c=""              # flag up and reset variables
} 
f {                          # between markers
    split($1,a,"[=;]")       # gather to 2 variables
    b=b a[1] "|"
    c=c a[2] "|"
}
```

Test it:

```
$ awk -f test.awk test.txt
IMSI|MSISDN|DEFCALL|CURRENTNAM|CAT|VOLTE_TAG|HLR_INDEX|PS_MSISDNLESS_SUPPORTED|CS_MSISDNLESS_SUPPORTED|CSRATTYPE|PSRATTYPE|ICI|STE|
xxxxxxxxxxxx|xxxxxxxxx|TS11|BOTH|COMMON|NOT_DEFINED|1|FALSE|FALSE|NO-NO-NO-NO-NO|NO-NO-NO-NO-NO|NO|NO|
```

Comment: That adds an extra `|` at the end of each line. Having said that the OP didn't SHOW us the end of each line in his question so who knows, maybe that's what the wants. It will also print the header row multiple times in the output instead of just once at the start, but again since the OP didn't SHOW us multiple blocks of input/output...

Comment: Hey, that was my excuse! :D

Answer (score 0):

Workaround using tr

```
tr -s '\n' ',' < file > tmpfile;
```

This gives me the output in form of

```
<SUBBEGIN    IMSI=xxxxxxxxxxxx;    MSISDN=xxxxxxxxx;    DEFCALL=TS11;    CURRENTNAM=BOTH;    CAT=COMMON;    VOLTE_TAG=NOT_DEFINED;    HLR_INDEX=1;    PS_MSISDNLESS_SUPPORTED=FALSE;    CS_MSISDNLESS_SUPPORTED=FALSE;    CSRATTYPE=NO-NO-NO-NO-NO;    PSRATTYPE=NO-NO-NO-NO-NO;    ICI=NO; STE=NO; <SUBEND
```

Replace the string `"<SUBBEGIN" with \n`

Answer (score 0):

Start with this one:

```
sed '/<SUBBEGIN/{:a;N;/\<SUBEND/!ba;s/\n[^=]*=/ /g;s/.*SUBBEGIN//;s/;/|/g}' input
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a different input file for simplicity

```
$ cat ip.txt 
<SUBBEGIN
    i1=abc;
    i2=ijk;
    i3=xyz;
    k1=NO;
    t1=YES;
<SUBEND

<SUBBEGIN
    i1=foo;
    i2=bar;
    i3=test;
    k1=YES;
    t1=NO;
<SUBEND

$ perl -nle '
$s=/<SUBBEGIN/ if /<SUB/;
if($s && !/<SUB/)
{
    ($k,$v) = /\S+(?==)|=\K[^;]+/g;
    push(@key, $k);
    push(@val, $v);
}
elsif(@key)
{
    print join "|", @key;
    print join "|", @val;
    @key = ();
    @val = ();
}
' ip.txt
i1|i2|i3|k1|t1
abc|ijk|xyz|NO|YES
i1|i2|i3|k1|t1
foo|bar|test|YES|NO
```

- `$s` set flag if input line contains `<SUBBEGIN`
- If flag is set and input line doesn't contain `<SUB`

  - extract key, value pair
  - populate them in two different arrays
- Once input line contains `<SUB` again

  - Check if one of the array (say `@key`) is not empty
  - print the key value arrays with `|` as separator
  - empty the arrays
- This will work whether there are empty lines or not between data structures

Answer (score 0):

Here is an another solution:

**awk script**

```
#!/bin/awk

function print_record( hdr )
{
    str = ""

    for( i = 1; i <= 13; i++ )
    {
        if( hdr )
        {
            value = substr( $i, 1, index( $i, "=" ) - 1 )
        }
        else
        {
            value = substr( $i, index( $i, "=" ) + 1 )
        }

        gsub( /^[ \t]+/, "", value )

        if( length(str) > 0 )
            str = str OFS

        str = str value
    }

    print str
}

BEGIN {
    RS="<SUBBEGIN\n"
    FS=";\n"
    hdr=1
    OFS="|"
}

{
    if( index( $0, "=" ) && index( $0, ";" ) )
    {
        if( hdr )
        {
            print_record( 1 )
            hdr = 0;
        }

        print_record( 0 )
    }
}

# eof #
```

**Input file**

```
<SUBBEGIN
    IMSI=xxxxxxxxxxxx;
    MSISDN=xxxxxxxxx;
    DEFCALL=TS11;
    CURRENTNAM=BOTH;
    CAT=COMMON;
    VOLTE_TAG=NOT_DEFINED;
    HLR_INDEX=1;
    PS_MSISDNLESS_SUPPORTED=FALSE;
    CS_MSISDNLESS_SUPPORTED=FALSE;
    CSRATTYPE=NO-NO-NO-NO-NO;
    PSRATTYPE=NO-NO-NO-NO-NO;
    ICI=NO;
    STE=NO;
<SUBEND
<SUBBEGIN
    IMSI=yyyyyyyyyy;
    MSISDN=yyyyyyyyy;
    DEFCALL=TS11;
    CURRENTNAM=BOTH;
    CAT=COMMON;
    VOLTE_TAG=NOT_DEFINED;
    HLR_INDEX=2;
    PS_MSISDNLESS_SUPPORTED=TRUE;
    CS_MSISDNLESS_SUPPORTED=FALSE;
    CSRATTYPE=NO-YES-NO-NO-NO;
    PSRATTYPE=NO-NO-NO-YES-NO;
    ICI=NO;
    STE=NO;
<SUBEND
<SUBBEGIN
    IMSI=zzzzzzzzzz;
    MSISDN=zzzzzzzzzzzzzzz;
    DEFCALL=TS11;
    CURRENTNAM=BOTH;
    CAT=COMMON;
    VOLTE_TAG=NOT_DEFINED;
    HLR_INDEX=3;
    PS_MSISDNLESS_SUPPORTED=FALSE;
    CS_MSISDNLESS_SUPPORTED=TRUE;
    CSRATTYPE=NO-YES-YES-NO-NO;
    PSRATTYPE=NO-NO-YES-YES-NO;
    ICI=YES;
    STE=YES;
<SUBEND
```

**Output**

```
$ awk -f script.awk -- input.txt
IMSI|MSISDN|DEFCALL|CURRENTNAM|CAT|VOLTE_TAG|HLR_INDEX|PS_MSISDNLESS_SUPPORTED|CS_MSISDNLESS_SUPPORTED|CSRATTYPE|PSRATTYPE|ICI|STE
xxxxxxxxxxxx|xxxxxxxxx|TS11|BOTH|COMMON|NOT_DEFINED|1|FALSE|FALSE|NO-NO-NO-NO-NO|NO-NO-NO-NO-NO|NO|NO
yyyyyyyyyy|yyyyyyyyy|TS11|BOTH|COMMON|NOT_DEFINED|2|TRUE|FALSE|NO-YES-NO-NO-NO|NO-NO-NO-YES-NO|NO|NO
zzzzzzzzzz|zzzzzzzzzzzzzzz|TS11|BOTH|COMMON|NOT_DEFINED|3|FALSE|TRUE|NO-YES-YES-NO-NO|NO-NO-YES-YES-NO|YES|YES
```

Hope It Helps!

Comment: You should mention it's gawk-specific due to the multi-char `RS`. Don't hard-code the number of fields as `13` when you could easily just count them from the input.

Answer (score 0):

with unix toolchain, perhaps the shortest...

```
$  sed '/^</d' file | tr '=' '\n' | tr -d ' ;' | pr -13ts'|'

IMSI|MSISDN|DEFCALL|CURRENTNAM|CAT|VOLTE_TAG|HLR_INDEX|PS_MSISDNLESS_SUPPORTED|CS_MSISDNLESS_SUPPORTED|CSRATTYPE|PSRATTYPE|ICI|STE
xxxxxxxxxxxx|xxxxxxxxx|TS11|BOTH|COMMON|NOT_DEFINED|1|FALSE|FALSE|NO-NO-NO-NO-NO|NO-NO-NO-NO-NO|NO|NO
```