# In bash shell how to split and pick up all values in key=value,key2=value

Tags: bash, shell

As the topic, the content should be:

```
key1=value1,key2=value2,key3=value3....
```

where **keyX... valueX... should be anything**
what I want, is just get out the result like:

```
value1 value2 value3
```

Comment: This answer should be good enough for you http://stackoverflow.com/a/29110625/5291015

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate question, but I answer it mysel:       echo "aa=1 bb=2 cc=3"|sed -r 's/[[:alnum:]]+=/\n&/g'|sed 's/.*=//g'|tr -s "\n" " "