# Shell Script : How to extract fields in variable positions by name from a string

Tags: linux, string, shell, cut, text-parsing

I have lines such as the following:

```
Mar 21 09:53:41 srv-1 kernel: [846595.861054] m5tomm7: IN=eth0 OUT=eth0 MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00 SRC=192.168.3.202 DST=192.168.2.99 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=126 ID=8076 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=62956 DPT=5358 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

and I want to extract the `SRC`, `DST`, `PROTO`, and `DPT` fields.

I cannot rely on using field *indices*, because they vary.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [awk parse out key=value pairs into variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29108949/awk-parse-out-key-value-pairs-into-variables)

Comment: You didn't indicate which shell you are going to use. If it is a shell where you can do regexp matching, you don't even need an external program to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 3):

```
# perl -ne will loop over the input data and run the following program
cat logfile | perl -ne '
    my $h = {}; # Declare a hash
    # match all KEY=VALUE pairs in the line 
    while ( m|(\w+)=(\S+)|g ) {
        $h->{$1} = $2; # Store ($1 = KEY, $2 = VALUE)
    };
    print join(",",$h->{SRC},$h->{DST},$h->{PROTO},$h->{DPT}) . "\n";
'
```

**output**

```
192.168.3.202,192.168.2.99,TCP,5358
```

Comment: No need for the pipeline, `perl -ne '...' log file`

Answer (score 2):

Combining `grep` with its `-P` option with `paste` allows for a simple solution (requires the GNU implementations):

```
$ grep -Po '\b(SRC|DST|PROTO|DPT)=\K[^ ]+' file | paste -s -d'   \n'
192.168.3.202 192.168.2.99 TCP 5358
```

- `-P` enables [PRCEs (Perl-compatible Regular Expressions)](http://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcre.html).
- `-o` outputs only the matching part(s) of the line, each match on its own output line.
- `\K` (a feature enabled by `-P`) drops everything matched so far; omit this, if you want the field names and `=` included in the output too (e.g., `SRC=192.168.3.202`).
- The `paste` command then joins every 4 lines with spaces to form a single line, by applying the separator (delimiter) string, `'   \n'`, cyclically - note how the string is composed of exactly 4 characters - 3 spaces and a newline - that matches the number of fields to extract per line.