# Extract multiple strings with awk

Tags: awk, match

I'm trying to extract two strings from each line, some lines don't have either string, some line has one string.

My input input.txt:

```
ID=MD001;refer=init;loc=tap2
ID=MD002;Name=Jam;refer=init;loc=tap2
ID=MD003;Name=Jane;Value=vip;refer=init;loc=tap2
ID=MD008;Name=George;product=car;vall=some;Value=vim;refer=init;loc=tap2
ID=MD0010;product=cars;Value=vip4;refer=init;loc=tap2
ID=MD0018;product=cars;
...
```

I want to match string "Name" or/and "Value", and output them out as:

```
ID=MD002 Name=Jam
ID=MD003 Name=Jane Value=vip
ID=MD008 Name=George Value=vim
ID=MD0010 Value=vip4
```

I tried:

`head input.txt | awk '$1 ~ /Name|Value/ {match($1, /(ID=*);.*(Name*);.*(Value.*)/, name); print name[1] name[2] name[3]}'`

But it did print anything.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse out key=value pairs into variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29108949/parse-out-key-value-pairs-into-variables)

Comment: When you apply [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59320486/8344060), you can easily do the requested by lines such as `{print map["ID","full"], map["Name","full"], map["Value","full"]}`

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=";"
}  
  {
  for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i~/^Name|^Value/){
      val=(val?val OFS:"")$i
    }
  }
  if(val){
    print $1,val;
  }
  val=""
}
'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows  for shown samples.

```
ID=MD002 Name=Jam
ID=MD003 Name=Jane Value=vip
ID=MD008 Name=George Value=vim
ID=MD0010 Value=vip4
```

Answer (score 1):

Start with this:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[=;]" }
{
    delete f
    for (i=1; i<NF; i+=2) {
        f[$i] = $i "=" $(i+1)
    }
    print f["ID"], f["Name"], f["Value"]
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
ID=MD001
ID=MD002 Name=Jam
ID=MD003 Name=Jane Value=vip
ID=MD008 Name=George Value=vim
ID=MD0010  Value=vip4
ID=MD0018
```

and then tweak to suit (using the `in` operator to test for presence) if you want to not print lines and/or not print missing values:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[=;]" }
{
    delete f
    for (i=1; i<NF; i+=2) {
        f[$i] = $i "=" $(i+1)
    }

    hit = 0
    out = f["ID"]
    out = out val("Name")
    out = out val("Value")
}
hit { print out }

function val(tag) {
    if (tag in f) {
        hit = 1
        return (OFS f[tag])
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
ID=MD002 Name=Jam
ID=MD003 Name=Jane Value=vip
ID=MD008 Name=George Value=vim
ID=MD0010 Value=vip4
```

Comment: You're welcome. Note that you can also rearrange the columns to output them in any order you want, you don;t have to output them in the same order as they were input.

Comment: Yes, by changing column name in f[""], you can print out column you need. Supper! Thanks Ed

Answer (score 1):

another similar `awk`

```
$ awk -F\; -v p='(Name|Value)=' '
       $0~p {printf "%s ", $1; 
             for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) if($i~p) printf "%s ", $i; 
             print ""}' file

ID=MD002 Name=Jam
ID=MD003 Name=Jane Value=vip
ID=MD008 Name=George Value=vim
ID=MD0010 Value=vip4
```

Answer (score 0):

And yet aother:

```
$ awk -F\; '{                                 # set the delim
    for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)                        # looping from the 2nd field
        if($i~/^(Name|Value)/) {              # looking for keywords and if found
           for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)                 # restart loop from beginning
               if($i~/^(Name|Value)/||i==1)   # outputing first field and matches
                   printf "%s ",$i
           print ""                           # newline in the end
           # next                             # breaking from the 1st loop not needed
        }
}' file
```

Output:

```
ID=MD002 Name=Jam 
ID=MD003 Name=Jane Value=vip 
ID=MD008 Name=George Value=vim 
ID=MD0010 Value=vip4
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be a good fit for awk's FPAT feature, where the fields are defined by their content rather than by their separators.  See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html

```
awk '
    BEGIN {
            FPAT = "(ID=[^;\v]+)|(Name=[^;\v]+)|(Value=[^;\v]+)"
    }

    NF>1 {
            # Only prints lines that have Name and/or Value
            for (i=1; i<NF; i++) {
                    printf $i " "
            }
            print $NF
    }
' file
```

The FPAT defines 3 possible fields.  The first, `(ID=[^;\v]+)`, means it must start with ID= and be followed by at least one character that is neither a semicolon nor a vertical whitespace.  The next two, `(Name=[^;\v]+)` and `(Value=[^;\v]+)`, similarly mean Name= or Value= followed by at least one character that is neither a semicolon nor vertical whitespace.