# What it is wrong with this awk filtering by patterns?

Tags: awk

I have this file `tes2`:

```
Topic:AURA.REP.JSON PartitionCount:1 ReplicationFactor:2 Configs:
Topic:AUX-SPS-WAVN.OPERATIONS PartitionCount:1 ReplicationFactor:2     Configs:min.insync.replicas=2,delete.retention.ms=86400000,retention.bytes=-1  
Topic:AUX-SPS-WAVN.OPERATIONS-DESA PartitionCount:3 ReplicationFactor:3 Configs:retention.ms=172800000
Topic:AUX-SPS-WAVN.ORPHAN-PUPPSS PartitionCount:1 ReplicationFactor:2 Configs:min.insync.replicas=2,delete.retention.ms=86400000,retention.bytes=-1
Topic:AUX-SPS-WAVN.ORPHAN-PUPPSS-DESA PartitionCount:3 ReplicationFactor:3 Configs:retention.ms=172800000
Topic:AUX-SPS-WAVN.ORPHAN-PUSRCI PartitionCount:1 ReplicationFactor:2 Configs:min.insync.replicas=2,delete.retention.ms=86400000,retention.bytes=-1
Topic:AUX-SPS-WAVN.ORPHAN-PUSRCI-DESA PartitionCount:3 ReplicationFactor:3 Configs:retention.ms=172800000
Topic:AUX-SPS-WAVN.ORPHAN-PUSUBP PartitionCount:1 ReplicationFactor:2 Configs:min.insync.replicas=2,delete.retention.ms=86400000,retention.bytes=-1
Topic:AUX-SPS-WAVN.ORPHAN-PUSUBP-DESA PartitionCount:3 ReplicationFactor:3 Configs:retention.ms=172800000
Topic:service_check_result PartitionCount:6 ReplicationFactor:1 Configs:cleanup.policy=delete,max.message.bytes=1000012,min.insync.replicas=1,retention.ms=604800000,delete.retention.ms=86400000,retention.bytes=-1
....
```

I want to filter by: Topic, PartitionCount, min.insync.replicas, cleanup.policy, retention.ms, max.message.bytes, retention.bytes

I am using this code:

```
awk '
  match($0,/Topic:[^ ]*/){
  topic=substr($0,RSTART+6,RLENGTH-6)
  match($0,/PartitionCount:[^ ]*/)
  partition=substr($0,RSTART+15,RLENGTH-15)
  match($0,/min\.insync\.replicas[^,]*/)
  mininsync=substr($0,RSTART+20,RLENGTH-20)
  match($0,/cleanup\.policy[^,]*/)
  cleanup=substr($0,RSTART+15,RLENGTH-15)
  match($0,/retention\.ms[^,]*/)
  retention=substr($0,RSTART+13,RLENGTH-13)
  match ($0,/max\.message\.bytes[^,]*/)
  maxmessage=substr($0,RSTART+18,RLENGTH-18)
  match ($0,/retention\.bytes[^,]*/)
  retentionbytes=substr($0,RSTART+16,RLENGTH-16)
  print 
  topic",",partition",",mininsync",",cleanup",",retention",",maxmessage",",retentionbytes 
  topic=""
}
' test2
```

But I get:

```
AURA.REP.JSON, 1, , , , , 
AUX-SPS-WAVN.OPERATIONS, 1, 2, , 86400000, , -1
, , SPS-WAVN.OPERATIONS-DESA, 3, , , 172800000
AUX-SPS-WAVN.ORPHAN-PUPPSS, 1, 2, , 86400000, , -1
, , SPS-WAVN.ORPHAN-PUPPSS-DESA, 3, , , 172800000
AUX-SPS-WAVN.ORPHAN-PUSRCI, 1, 2, , 86400000, , -1
, , SPS-WAVN.ORPHAN-PUSRCI-DESA, 3, , , 172800000
AUX-SPS-WAVN.ORPHAN-PUSUBP, 1, 2, , 86400000, , -1
, , SPS-WAVN.ORPHAN-PUSUBP-DESA, 3, , , 172800000
```

I don't know why.

Thanks

Comment: `match($0,/Topic:[^ ]*/)` just `/Topic:[^ ]*/{...`. Och, you use `RSTART` later. `But I get:` Please post the expected output you want to get. A little bit of comment would be advisable. What does your awk code currently do? What are those `-18` `+18`? `I want to filter by` What does it mean "filter by"? You want to exclude all lines that do not include those information (as this is what "filter" means)? Or do you want to _transform_ the line into a different format? What format would that be?

Comment: Instead of `substr`. Use `gensub`

Comment: Could you please confirm if you want to get values for each line? If yes then your output may come like that since many of the strings are NOT present in lines(what I could see from shown samples), kindly do let us know on same.

Comment: Also please do mention expected output in your post and let us know then.

Comment: Does the file contain CRLF line endings?

Comment: Hi Skiel and Welcome to Stackoverflow. You indicate the output which you are receiving, but your are not mentioning what you are expecting to receive. Could you enlighten us?

Comment: You might be interested in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59320486/8344060

Comment: As already mentioned in the comments, `filter by` is ambiguous - change `filter by` to `print` or `delete`, whichever one you mean.

Answer (score 0):

You have an input file of the form:

```
key1:value1 key2:value2 key3:value3
```

of which one of the values has the form:

```
key1=value1,key2=value2,key3=value3
```

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59320486/8344060) we can make the following code:

```
awk '
    function str2map(str,fs1,fs2,map,   n,tmp) {
       n=split(str,map,fs1)
       for (;n>0;n--) { 
         split(map[n],tmp,fs2);
         map[tmp[1]]=tmp[2]; map[tmp[1],"full"]=map[n]
         delete map[n]
       }
    }
    BEGIN{OFS=","}
    { str2map($0," ",":",map_main) }
    { str2map(map_main["Configs"],",","=",map_config) }
    { print map_main["Topic"], map_main["PartitionCount"],                      \
            map_config["min.insync.replicas"], map_config["cleanup.policy"],    \
            map_config["delete.retention.ms"], map_config["max.message.bytes"], \
            map_config["retention.bytes"]
    }' file
```

This creates the following output:

```
AURA.REP.JSON,1,,,,,
AUX-SPS-WAVN.OPERATIONS,1,2,,86400000,,-1
AUX-SPS-WAVN.OPERATIONS-DESA,3,,,,,
AUX-SPS-WAVN.ORPHAN-PUPPSS,1,2,,86400000,,-1
AUX-SPS-WAVN.ORPHAN-PUPPSS-DESA,3,,,,,
AUX-SPS-WAVN.ORPHAN-PUSRCI,1,2,,86400000,,-1
AUX-SPS-WAVN.ORPHAN-PUSRCI-DESA,3,,,,,
AUX-SPS-WAVN.ORPHAN-PUSUBP,1,2,,86400000,,-1
AUX-SPS-WAVN.ORPHAN-PUSUBP-DESA,3,,,,,
service_check_result,6,1,delete,86400000,1000012,-1
```