# How do I detect embbeded field names and reorder fields using awk?

Tags: regex, awk, freebsd

I have the following data:

```
"b":1.14105,"a":1.14106,"x":48,"t":1594771200000
"a":1.141,"b":1.14099,"x":48,"t":1594771206000
...
```

I am trying to display data in a given order and only for three fields. As the fields order is not guaranteed, I need to read the "tag" for each comma separated column for each line.

I have tried to solve this task using `awk`:

```
awk -F',' '
                {
                        for(i=1; i<=$NF; i++) {
                                if(index($i,"\"a\":")!=0) a=$i;
                                if(index($i,"\"b\":")!=0) b=$i;
                                if(index($i,"\"t\":")!=0) t=$i;
                        }
                        printf("%s,%s,%s\n",a,b,t);
                }
        '
```

But I get:

```
,,
,,
...
```

In the above data sample, I would expect:

```
"a":1.14106,"b":1.14105,"t":1594771200000
"a":1.141,"b":1.14099,"t":1594771206000
...
```

Note: I am using the awk shipped with FreeBSD

Comment: Was this JSON before?

Comment: Maybe this answer might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59320486/8344060

Comment: @Cyrus yes it was JSON before (in case you have any suggerstion for parsing JSON on command line without using a  programming language)

Comment: @M.E.: I suggest to start a new question with a valid JSON file if you have access to `jq` or `perl`.

Comment: I definitively do not want to use `perl` I know how to do it with `Python` or `Java` but I am trying to avoid using them via simple tools. Here is the JQ question in case you want to help me to incorporate JQ into my toolset: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62938833/how-do-i-extract-a-json-list-into-a-csv-in-command-line-using-jq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `awk` and an array:

```
awk -F '[:,]' '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i=i+2){a[$i]=$(i+1)}; print "\"a\":" a["\"a\""] ",\"b\":" a["\"b\""] ",\"t\":" a["\"t\""]}' file
```

or

```
awk -F '[":,]' '{for(i=2; i<=NF; i=i+4){a[$i]=$(i+2)}; print "\"a\":" a["a"] ",\"b\":" a["b"] ",\"t\":" a["t"]}' file
```

Output:

```
"a":1.14106,"b":1.14105,"t":1594771200000
"a":1.141,"b":1.14099,"t":1594771206000
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FS = "[,:]"
    OFS = ","
}
{
    for (i=1; i<NF; i+=2) {
        f[$i] = $(i+1)
    }
    print p("a"), p("b"), p("t")
}

function p(tag, t) {
    t = "\"" tag "\""
    return t ":" f[t]
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
"a":1.14106,"b":1.14105,"t":1594771200000
"a":1.141,"b":1.14099,"t":1594771206000
```

Comment: That answer is less ugly than mine. +1

Comment: @Cyrus I removed the '"' characters in advance with sed and modified slightly your answer (actually I just need the values) and I still find your answer easier to read than this one -which means just that, that I find yours easier to read and follow by me-

Comment: M.E. hopefully it's obvious that without the `"`s and just printing the values my answer and @Cyrus's would reduce to identical scripts other than the array name (he used `a[]`, I used `f[]`). The main difference between our 2 scripts is in choosing how to format the output fields - he went with writing out `"\"a\":" a["a"]` for each field, I went with a function that converts `"a"` to ``"\"a\":" a["a"]`` so you can just write `p("a")` for each field. The other difference of whether `"` is considered part of the FS or not is fluff and if you don't have `"`s in the fields just goes away.

Answer (score 2):

similar `awk` where you can specify the fields and order.

```
$ awk -F[:,] -v fields='"a","b","t"' 'BEGIN{n=split(fields,f)} 
            {for(i=1;i<NF;i+=2) map[$i]=$(i+1); 
             for(i=1;i<=n;i++) printf "%s", f[i]":"map[f[i]] (i==n?ORS:",")}' file

"a":1.14106,"b":1.14105,"t":1594771200000
"a":1.141,"b":1.14099,"t":1594771206000
```