# How do I extract a JSON list into a CSV in command line using JQ?

Tags: json, export-to-csv, precision, jq

I have the following JSON data:

```
% cat test2 

{"day":"2020-07-15","map":
{"a":"ask","b":"bid","t":"timestamp"},"msLatency":52,"pair":"EUR/USD","status":"success","ticks":[
{"b":1.14105,"a":1.14106,"x":48,"t":1594771200000},
{"b":1.14105,"a":1.14106,"x":48,"t":1594771201000},
{"b":1.14103,"a":1.14104,"x":48,"t":1594771202000},
{"b":1.141,"a":1.1413,"x":48,"t":1594771203000},
{"b":1.14103,"a":1.14104,"x":48,"t":1594771205000},
{"b":1.14094,"a":1.14095,"x":48,"t":1594778803000}],"type":"forex"}
```

And I want to get:

```
1.14105,1.14106,1594771200000
1.14105,1.14106,1594771201000
1.14103,1.14104,1594771202000
1.141,1.1413,1594771203000
1.14103,1.14104,1594771205000
1.14094,1.14095,1594778803000
```

Ideally the output shall also pad with zeros, with 1 and 5 being parameters to specify that the first two columns are numbers with 1 natural place and 5 decimal places (although this step can be done easily with `awk`):

```
1.14105,1.14106,1594771200000
1.14105,1.14106,1594771201000
1.14103,1.14104,1594771202000
1.14100,1.14130,1594771203000
1.14103,1.14104,1594771205000
1.14094,1.14095,1594778803000
```

I have tried this with JQ:

```
 % cat test2 | jq '.ticks'
[
  {
    "b": 1.14105,
    "a": 1.14106,
    "x": 48,
    "t": 1594771200000
  },
  {
    "b": 1.14105,
    "a": 1.14106,
    "x": 48,
    "t": 1594771201000
  },
  {
    "b": 1.14103,
    "a": 1.14104,
    "x": 48,
    "t": 1594771202000
  },
  {
    "b": 1.141,
    "a": 1.1413,
    "x": 48,
    "t": 1594771203000
  },
  {
    "b": 1.14103,
    "a": 1.14104,
    "x": 48,
    "t": 1594771205000
  },
  {
    "b": 1.14094,
    "a": 1.14095,
    "x": 48,
    "t": 1594778803000
  }
]
```

But I am stuck on how to turn this into a CSV.

EDIT:
Just as reference, I previously had the following parsing, using JQ here is much simpler option:

```
cat test2 |
sed -e 's/{\"/#{\"/g' |
tr '#' '\n' |
grep -v "timestamp" |
grep -v "day" |
sed '/^[[:space:]]*$/d' |
sed 's/].*$//g' |
sed 's/{//g' |
sed 's/},//g' |
sed 's/}//g' |
sed 's/\"//g' |
awk -F '[:,]' -v decimal_places=5 -v integer_places=1 '{
        for(i=1; i<=NF; i=i+2) {
                value[$i]=$(i+1);
        };
        format_price="%0" integer_places "." decimal_places "f"
        format=format_price " " format_price " %d\n"
        printf(format,value["b"],value["a"],value["t"]);
}'
```

Comment: I know I've done this before, and it was surprisingly difficult to do with `jq`. Honestly, I'd forget about using `jq` for this task and use python (or practically any other language). Just unmarshal the JSON into a dict, and then pick out the elements you want and print them. That will be much easier.

Comment: Thanks for the advise, let's see if there are other opinions or examples on how to do this with JQ. As a reference, piping `sed` and `awk` is relatively easy as you build the parsing with small steps. However, while asking about the last step in `awk` I was suggested that JQ might help for this case too though. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62925668/how-do-i-detect-embbeded-field-names-and-reorder-fields-using-awk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```
jq -r '.ticks[] | [.b, .a, .t] | join(",")' test2

1.14105,1.14106,1594771200000
1.14105,1.14106,1594771201000
1.14103,1.14104,1594771202000
1.141,1.1413,1594771203000
1.14103,1.14104,1594771205000
1.14094,1.14095,1594778803000
```

It doesn't do the padding to 5 digits. I have no idea how to do that in `jq`. I still think another language would be easier.

Comment: It looks a simple solution (probably once you know how to chain the different steps in jq). Thanks a lot, I think this is useful to parse these kind of JSON files.

Answer (score 1):

You can very well write your own padding function for this. First extract the number of digits following the decimal digit and decide on the padding digits accordingly.

You can put together a script, name it `script.jq` and do below. Note that the logic below will *not* work for numbers in scientific notation.

```
#!/usr/bin/jq -f

def pad($len): 
  tostring | 
  match("^([0-9]*).([0-9]+)$").captures[1].length as $dec |
  ($len - $dec) as $l  |
  . + ("0" * ($l)) [:$l];

.ticks[] | [ (.b|pad(5)), (.a|pad(5)), .t ] | join(",")
```

and call it with the `jq` executable

```
jq -r -f script.jq json
```

which now produces a properly padded output

```
1.14105,1.14106,1594771200000
1.14105,1.14106,1594771201000
1.14103,1.14104,1594771202000
1.14100,1.14130,1594771203000
1.14103,1.14104,1594771205000
1.14094,1.14095,1594778803000
```

Note: The `pad($len)` is inspired from [pkoppstein's comment](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/2033#issuecomment-586083471) from [stedolan/jq - pad function #2033](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/2033)

Comment: Thanks for the example Inian, I find much easier to do that task with `awk` though, as it uses printf (see edited question). I finally combined jq with awk to provide the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idiomatic jq-only solution to the problem, understood to require that the number of digits to the right of a decimal point, if present, be as specified.  The -r command-line option should be used.

```
# format numbers whose tostring representation has a decimal point
# so that the number of digits to the right of the decimal point is $dd
# assuming $dd >= 0
def format($dd):
  def rpad: (. + $dd * "0") | .[:$dd];
  tostring
  | index(".") as $dec
  | if $dec then .[0:$dec+1] + (.[$dec+1:]|rpad)
    else .
    end ;

.ticks[]
| [(.b | format(1)), (.a | format(5)), .t ]
| join(",")
```