# print certain words that begins with x from one line

Tags: parsing, awk, syslog

i want to somehow print words where the word starts with for example srcip and srcintf, from this line from /var/log/syslog

```
Jul 21 13:13:35 some-name date=2020-07-21 time=13:13:34 devname="devicename" devid="deviceid" logid="0000000013" type="traffic" subtype="forward" level="notice" vd="root" eventtime=1595330014 srcip=1.2.3.4 srcport=57324 srcintf="someinterface" srcintfrole="wan" dstip=5.6.7.8 dstport=80 dstintf="anotherinterface" dstintfrole="lan" sessionid=supersecretid proto=6 action="deny" policyid=0 policytype="policy" service="HTTP" dstcountry="Sweden" srccountry="Sweden" trandisp="noop" duration=0 sentbyte=0 rcvdbyte=0 sentpkt=0 appcat="unscanned" crscore=30 craction=131072 crlevel="high"
```

to something that looks like this

```
date=2020-07-21 time=13:13:34 devname="devicename" action="deny" policyid=0 srcintf="someinterface" dstintf="anotherinterface" srcip=1.2.3.4 srcport=57324 -----> dstip=5.6.7.8 dstport=80
```

currently im using awk to do it. the scalability of it is pretty bad for obvious reasons:

```
cat /var/log/syslog | awk '{print $5,$6,$7,$25,$26,$17,$21,$15,$16,"-----> "$19,$20}'
```

also not all the lines have *srcip* in the same "field". so some lines are really skewed.

or would a syslog message rewriter be better for this purpose? how would you go about solving this? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    delete f
    for (i=5; i<=NF; i++) {
        split($i,tmp,/=/)
        f[tmp[1]] = $i
    }

    print f["date"], f["time"], f["devname"], f["action"], f["policyid"], f["srcintf"], \
         f["dstintf"], f["srcip"], f["srcport"], "----->", f["dstip"], f["dstport"]
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
date=2020-07-21 time=13:13:34 devname="devicename" action="deny" policyid=0 srcintf="someinterface" dstintf="anotherinterface" srcip=1.2.3.4 srcport=57324 -----> dstip=5.6.7.8 dstport=80
```

The above assumes your quoted strings do not contain spaces as shown in your sample input.

Comment: @kvantour I added the `delete f`, thanks. I don't think it's required for this OP but it doesn't hurt and other people reading this with slightly different requirements might benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

I present you an awk answer which is flexible and, instead of a simple one-liner, a bit a more programmatic way. Your log-file has lines that look in general like:

```
key1=value1 key2=value2 key3=value3 ...
```

The idea in this awk is to break it down into an array in awk which is associative, so that the elements can be called as:

```
a[key1]=>value1 a[key2]=>value2 ... a[key2,"full"]=>key2=value2 ...
```

Using a function which is explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59320486/8344060), you can write:

```
awk '
    function str2map(str,fs1,fs2,map,   n,tmp) {
       n=split(str,map,fs1)
       for (;n>0;n--) { 
         split(map[n],tmp,fs2);
         map[tmp[1]]=tmp[2]; map[tmp[1],"full"]=map[n]
         delete map[n]
       }
    }
    { str2map($0," ","=",a) }
    { print a["date","full"],a["time","full"],a["devname","full"],a["action","full"] }
   ' file
```

This method is very flexible. There is also no dependency in the order of the line or whatever.

**note:** the above method does not take care of quoting. So if a space appears within a quoted string, it might mess things up.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `filter.awk`:

```
BEGIN{
   split(filter,a,",");
   for (i in a){
      f[a[i]]=1;
   }
}
{
   for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
      split($i,b,"=");
      if (b[1] in f){
         printf("%s ", $i);
      }
   }
   printf("\n");
}
```

you can do:

```
awk -v filter="srcip,srcintf" -f filter.awk  /var/log/syslog
```

In the filter you specify, comma separated, the keywords. It has to find

note: this script also assumed there file is of the form: `key1=value key2=value` and that there are no space in the values.

Comment: The third arg to `split()` is a regexp, not a string, so you should try to get used to using regexp instead of string delimiters so that doesn't bite you one day. `split(filter,a,/,/)` and `split($i,b,/=/)`

Comment: From the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html): "The third argument, fieldpat, is a regexp describing the fields in string (just as FPAT is a regexp describing the fields in input records). It may be either a regexp constant or a string."   yes, really,  it ends with "or a string"

Comment: That's correct, you **can** specify a string there when you need to, but awk converts that string to a regexp first and **then** `split()` uses it as such so when you do provide a string it gets parsed twice by awk which means you get some extra complexity such as having to double up on escapes and so it's something you only do when you **need** to do it, much like leaving the quotes off shell variables - you **can** do it when you **need** to.

Comment: Co-incidentally this same issue just came up in a different question with a different function - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63019452/how-to-perform-this-string-replacement-using-awk#comment111443162_63019452.