# How to use awk or regular expression to filter log

Tags: awk

log format:

```
indexQuery.end, index=ssp_item_info, routing=188902615, total=0, nextScrollOffset=, logicTimeCost=3[ms]|
```

I want to filter some logs in which the logicTimeCost is higher than 300ms, how can I do that

Comment: Kindly do add your efforts in form of code in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59320486/8344060) answer. You can them implement the same thing with `fs1=", *"` and `fs2="="`. The script would then look like `awk 'function str2map { ... }; {str2map($0,", *","=",map)}(map["logicTimeCost"]+0>300)' file` The latter is not converting your units to seconds or  mili seconds if the unit can be different to ms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using GNU awk you might also use a pattern with a range from 300 up

```
awk '/logicTimeCost=([3-9][0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]{3,})\[ms\]/' file
```

The range matches

- `[3-9][0-9]{2}` Match from 300 till 999
- `|` Or
- `[1-9][0-9]{3,}` Match from a 1000 up

Or a bit longer version using awk

```
awk '/logicTimeCost=([3-9][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]+)\[ms\]/' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`, where `thr=300` is the variable by which we are checking the condition.

```
awk -v thr="300" '
match($0,/logicTimeCost=[0-9]+\[ms\]/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  gsub(/[^0-9]*/,"",val)
  if(val>thr){ print }
}
'  Input_file
```

Answer (score -1):

With GNU awk, you can use the match command to find lines which contain the field you're looking for, and store the numeric portion into an array which you compare against the value you care about.

```
awk 'match($0, / logicTimeCost=([[:digit:]]+)/, m){ if(m[1]>300) print $0 }'
```

As an example, here's some input with the fields shuffled around. Note that it finds the field wherever it is in the line.

```
sauer@GRODD:~> cat /tmp/input 
indexQuery.end, index=ssp_item_info, routing=188902615, total=0, nextScrollOffset=, logicTimeCost=3[ms]|
indexQuery.end, index=ssp_item_info, routing=188902615, total=0, nextScrollOffset=, logicTimeCost=400[ms]|
indexQuery.end, index=ssp_item_info, routing=188902615, total=0, nextScrollOffset=, logicTimeCost=300[ms]|
indexQuery.end, index=ssp_item_info, logicTimeCost=301[ms], routing=188902615, total=0,1|
sauer@GRODD:~> awk 'match($0, / logicTimeCost=([[:digit:]]+)/, m){ if(m[1]>300) print $0 }' < /tmp/input 
indexQuery.end, index=ssp_item_info, routing=188902615, total=0, nextScrollOffset=, logicTimeCost=400[ms]|
indexQuery.end, index=ssp_item_info, logicTimeCost=301[ms], routing=188902615, total=0,1|
```

I like this a little better than most of the other answers because it does a proper numeric comparison instead of comparing numbers with a regex.  If you decide the threshold is 278 or 306 later, using a regex to find greater values suddenly becomes *waaaaay* harder.  RavinderSingh13's answer was pretty close to this, though.