# How to read key=value variables from one file and replace ${key} in another file?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Similar to e.g. this: [Parse out key=value pairs into variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29108949/parse-out-key-value-pairs-into-variables)

`.env`

```
key1=value1
key2=value2
```

`config.yml`

```yaml
some:
  key1: ${key1}
  key2: ${key2}
```

How can I replace the values in `config.yml` with the values from `.env`?

So far I got this:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {n=index($1,"=");if(n){vars[substr($i, 1, n - 1)]=substr($i, n + 1)}; next } { for (i in vars) gsub("${"i"}", vars[i]) }1' .env file.yml
                                                                                                                  ^- Can't figure out how to replace $
```

I can make it work with `{key1}` but not with `${key1}`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Use a dotenv parser and *generate* `config.yml`, rather than trying to make `config.yml` a template.

Comment: It's meant as a workaround for https://github.com/opendistro-for-elasticsearch/security/issues/24 (env variables aren't substituted, even though they should be)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest would be:

```
. .env
export key1 key2
envsubst '$key1 $key2' < config.yml
```

> Can't figure out how to replace $

Seems you have to escape `$` and `{` and `}`, like:

```
gsub("\\$\\{"i"\\}", vars[i])
```

Comment: An alternative: `. <(sed 's/^/export /' .env); envsubst <config.yml`

Comment: `.env` files are not necessarily valid shell scripts.

Comment: Thanks, I struggled with the correct escaping. `envsubst` would be perfect but doesn't work if the value contains `=`

Comment: `envsubst would be perfect but doesn't work if the value contains =` Works for me: https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/ProudOverdueSet#main.sh

Answer (score 1):

Without using `awk`:

```sh
(set -a; source .env; envsubst < config.yml)

some:
  key1: value1
  key2: value2
```

- `(...)`: Runs command line in a sub-shell to avoid polluting current shell's environment
- `set -a`: Exports all declaring variables
- `source .env`: Source in `.env` file
- `envsubst < config.yml`: Substitutes env variables in `config.yml`

Comment: `.env` files are not necessarily valid shell scripts; `source` is not a reliable way of turning those variables into shell variables.

Comment: ok I just saw a sample in OP's question and that does look like shell variables.

Comment: The standard example of divergence from https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv: `JSON={"foo": "bar"}`. `.env` files don't require the RHS to be quoted. `foo="x\ny"` is also a multiple line string, not a single 4-character string.